# Is it possible to use OpenId Connect with Sylius?

Tags: symfony, keycloak, openid-connect, sylius

I found OAuth documentation for Sylius but nothing about OpenId Connect (OIDC). I use keycloak as identity provider and want to use keycloak login box to connect to Sylius shop. Is it possible?

I already looked at this doc which explain how to add social login with facebook, but it's not so simple with keycloak:

https://docs.sylius.com/en/1.12/cookbook/shop/facebook-login.html
https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/c36bf2291c36ef04f62e0bc404cd09db333a7f00/docs/resource_owners/keycloak.md

Actually, I have this configuration:

In config/packages/security.yaml:

```
providers:
    sylius_admin_user_provider:
        id: sylius.admin_user_provider.email_or_name_based
    sylius_api_admin_user_provider:
        id: sylius.admin_user_provider.email_or_name_based
    sylius_shop_user_provider:
        id: sylius.shop_user_provider.email_or_name_based
    sylius_api_shop_user_provider:
        id: sylius.shop_user_provider.email_or_name_based
...

firewalls:
    ...
    shop:
        oauth:
            resource_owners:
                keycloak: "/login/check-keycloak"
            login_path: sylius_shop_login
            use_forward: false
            failure_path: sylius_shop_login

            oauth_user_provider:
                service: sylius.oauth.user_provider
        provider: sylius_shop_user_provider
```

In config/packages/hwi_oauth.yaml:

```
    resource_owners:
    keycloak:
        type:                keycloak
        base_url:            https://auth.test.mycompany.fr/
        realm:               MontRoyal
        client_id:           sylius-poc-1
        client_secret:       *secret*
        scope:               "email"
```

In config/routes.yaml:

```
hwi_oauth_redirect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/redirect.xml"
    prefix: /connect

hwi_oauth_connect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/connect.xml"
    prefix: /connect

hwi_oauth_login:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/login.xml"
    prefix: /login

keycloak:
    path: /login/check-keycloak
```

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.